# Is the matrix exponential and the Jordan canonical form actually useful for solving differential equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, fluid-dynamics, nonlinear-equations

All of my yearlong graduate-level Linear Algebra course notes from my professor—an algebraist/representation theorist—shows his love for the exponential map $e^A$ and the *Jordan canonical form*—and one main reason given by him is that they help solve linear differential equations.

But how true is this in practice?

I have little scientific computing experience.

The thing is, in my research interest, *fluid dynamics*, not only are the evolution equations nonlinear, often with nonconstant coefficients. Do the matrix exponential and the Jordan form help with modeling and simulation in *fluid dynamics problems*?

Comment: Krylov subspace methods for computing matrix exponential-vector products are more often used because they save significant time compared to diagonalization/Jordan form and other direct methods of computing the exponential and performing the multiplication

Comment: Fluids are often their own beast as far as algorithms but check out "exponential integrators" for the state-of-the-art in computing and utilizing matrix exponentials